# auto Submit form on max length, - add a java script code for existing one

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to auto submit form when the input reaches 7 characters. i have tried few java script codes, but it is spoiling my script functioning.

can any one please help me in this.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "GetCustomerData.php?id="; // The server-side script
       function handleHttpResponse() {  
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
              if(http.status==200) {
                var results=http.responseText;
              document.getElementById('divCustomerInfo').innerHTML = results;
              }
            }
        }

        function requestCustomerInfo() {      
            var sId = document.getElementById("txtCustomerId").value;
            http.open("GET", url + escape(sId), true);
            http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
            http.send(null);
        }
function getHTTPObject() {
  var xmlhttp;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (!xmlhttp){
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }

}
  return xmlhttp;


}
var http = getHTTPObject(); // We create the HTTP Object
</script>

<form id="form_home">
    <p>Enter customer ID number to retrieve information:</p>
    <p>Customer ID: <input type="text" maxlength="7" id="txtCustomerId" value="" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="requestCustomerInfo()" /></p>
</form>

    <div id="divCustomerInfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will submit the form when the text box reaches 7 chars:

```
document.getElementById('txtCustomerId').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

    if(this.value.length === 7) {
        document.getElementById('form_home').submit();
    }
});
```

Here is a demo of it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/TuVN2/1/

Looking at your markup, I guess you want to run requestCustomerInfo() and not submit. If you submit the response will never be handled. To do this you would move the function call into the keyup handler:

```
document.getElementById('txtCustomerId').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

    if(this.value.length === 7) {
        requestCustomerInfo();
    }

});
```

I would also not recommend hand rolling your ajax handler. Consider using a library like jQuery.

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more explicit. This is not a drop in solution - ask if you need help understanding what is going on.